# Unable to dispatch createAsyncThunk from a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

```
type UserState = {
  token: string | null;
  loginError: Boolean;
};

const initialState: UserState = {
  token: null,
  loginError: false,
};

export const auth = createAsyncThunk<
  string,
  { email: string; password: string }
>("user/login", async (user: { email: string; password: string }) => {
  const response = await srvAuth(user);
  return response.data.tokens.access.token;
});

const UserSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(auth.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.token = action.payload;
      state.loginError = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(auth.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loginError = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(auth.pending, (state, action) => {});
  },
});

export default UserSlice.reducer;
```

Now in component:
useAppDispatch is being exported from the hooks.ts file

```
import { useAppDispatch } from "../redux/hooks";
import { auth } from "../redux/slices/UserSlice";

const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
onClick={() => {
              //Error on the line below
              dispatch(auth({ email, password }));
}}
```

hooks.ts file:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from "./store";

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Upon dispatching I get Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
Trying out Redux toolkit in a Next.js app with TypeScript. How do I resolve this ? TIA

Comment: On which line are you getting that error? How is `useAppDispatch` defined? How do you import `auth`?

Comment: It's not an error of dispatch calling. It's a type script error. What is happening on the 2554 line?

Comment: import { auth } from "../redux/slices/UserSlice";
import { useAppDispatch } from "../redux/hooks";

useAppDispatch is being exported from a hooks.ts file like this:
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>;

Error is on this line:  dispatch(auth({ email, password }));

Comment: @phry  please refer to the comment. I have also edit the original post.

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov please refer to the comment. I have also edit the original post.

Comment: @user20334904  pls show the useAppDispatch code

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov edited original post with hooks.ts file

Comment: You should call useDispatch, not just return. `export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();` instead of `export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>;`

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov oops! I somehow missed it in the official tutorial. Thanks for helping me out, much appreciated.